# query pre data by filter condition

Tags: oracle

| total_assets | day_yield | create_date |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 100 | 0.01 | 20171026 |
| 200 | -0.01 | 20171027 |
| 300 | -0.01 | 20171028 |
| 400 | -0.01 | 20171029 |

expect result:

| total_assets | day_yield | create_date | create_date |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 100 | 0.01 | 20171026 | null |
| 200 | -0.01 | 20171027 | 100 |
| 300 | -0.01 | 20171028 | 100 |
| 400 | -0.01 | 20171029 | 100 |

when create_date='20171029' then find pre data of day_yiel>0,the result 100

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `LAG` with a `CASE` expression to find the most recent positive value (ignoring `NULL` values):

```sql
SELECT t.*,
       LAG(CASE WHEN day_yield > 0 THEN total_assets END)
         IGNORE NULLS OVER (ORDER BY create_date)
         AS last_yield
FROM   table_name t
```

Which, for the sample data:

```sql
CREATE TABLE table_name(total_assets, day_yield, create_date) AS
SELECT 100, +0.01, DATE '2017-10-26' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 200, -0.01, DATE '2017-10-27' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 300, -0.01, DATE '2017-10-28' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 400, -0.01, DATE '2017-10-29' FROM DUAL;
```

Outputs:

| TOTAL_ASSETS | DAY_YIELD | CREATE_DATE | LAST_YIELD |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 100 | .01 | 2017-10-26 00:00:00 | *null* |
| 200 | -.01 | 2017-10-27 00:00:00 | 100 |
| 300 | -.01 | 2017-10-28 00:00:00 | 100 |
| 400 | -.01 | 2017-10-29 00:00:00 | 100 |

[fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/GnDxIpJN)